# Are strings in AWK treated as arrays?

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm pretty new to awk/gawk and I found this a little confusing. I hope you may help me shed some light on this question: **Are strings in awk treated as array of chars?**

I've read something about the stringy-ness of this computing language, so I tried to make a script like this:

```
BEGIN {
   myArray[1] = "foo"
   myArray[2] = "bar"
   myArray[3] = 42

   awkward()
}

function awkward() {
    for (j in myArray) {
        for (d in myArray[j]) {
            # error!
        }
    }
}
```

Was I naive in thinking something like this could work? It actually does not work with my version of `gawk`, giving me this error:

```
for (d in myArray[j]) {
                 ^ syntax error
```

Can anybody help me to understand more about why this should not work? Bonus: can anybody share their workaround on this?

---

To clarify a bit, I'm trying to access the content of `myArray[j]` char by char, using a for loop on index `d`.

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice workaround @MichaWiedenmann. It is indeed a way to achieve the goal, yet does not explain why this does not turn magically into a multidimensional array.

Comment: @DaemonPainter see also https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, strings in awk are not treated as array of chars. Use `substr()`:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN {
   myArray[1] = "foo"
   myArray[2] = "bar"
   myArray[3] = 42

   awkward()
}

function awkward() {
    for (j in myArray) {
        for (i=1;i<=length(myArray[j]);i++) {  # here
            print substr(myArray[j],i,1)       # and here
        }
    }
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk
f
o
o
b
a
r
4
2
```

Comment: Bonus: so they are? What are they?

Comment: Strings are self-defined: they are strings.